# How much arteries expand during systole?

Tags: blood-circulation

Arteries expand during systole. By what percentage, on an average, does the arteries' diameter change during systole  with respect to diastole? Answer may depend upon type of artery i.e. elastic artery,  muscular artery, arterioles etc, you may specify the type.

This 
https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.nature.com/articles/eye199419.pdf%3Forigin%3Dppub&ved=2ahUKEwjuy4_Z2rvaAhWMYo8KHXuVAfcQFjAFegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw3L27QesaUFNIqGfkINgy-7
paper shows 3-4% change in diameter of retinal arteries, but size of the arteries is roughly 100 microns. I am more interested in arteries with diameter more than 1 mm.